# How do I write to a video file from an LWJGL Display?

Tags: java, lwjgl, video-processing

So I have learnt how to take a screenshot of my LWJGL Display by reading the byte buffer from GL_FRONT with:

```
public static void takeScreenShot(){
    GL11.glReadBuffer(GL11.GL_FRONT);
    int width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    int bpp = 4;
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * bpp);
    GL11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_NSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
    File file = new File(screenshot_dir + "\\" + datetime + ".png");
    String format = "PNG";
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, Bufferedmage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int i = (x + (width * y)) * bpp;
            int r = buffer.get(i) & 0xFF;
            int g = buffer.get(i + 1) & 0xFF;
            int b = buffer.get(i + 2) & 0xFF;
            image.setRGB(x, height - (y + 1), (0xFF << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | );
        }
    }
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, format, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I assume I can just keep reading from the front buffer about 60 times a second (I know this will dramatically decrease performance). Then I can just write a certain number of frames into a buffer, which would be swapped to another when it is full. After a buffer is full, its contents can then be appended to a file.

How do I format the byte buffers to be frames in a video?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is indeed very old, but for the sake of completeness, I'm going to answer it anyways.

My answer is *too big* to provide examples or explain. That's why I'm linking other people's tutorials and official documentation.

1. Render the scene (or whatever) to a 2D texture. (http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/)
2. Retrieve the texture data using `glGetTexImage` (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml)
3. Download a Java Library for encoding MP4 (or whatever you want) and encode frame after frame.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
create framebuffer
enable framebuffer
for all frames {
    render to framebuffer
    glGetTexImage(...)
    library.encodeFrame(imageData)
}
```

This is very general and it depends heavily on the library you use for encoding.