# How to render a LWJGL game scene to a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am currently working on a project that involves rendering LWJGL game scenes to a video stream instead of a window. I believe I can achieve that if I render a game scene to an intermediate format, such as a ByteBuffer. I am trying to extend LWJGL `VoxelGame` [demo](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/main/src/org/lwjgl/demo/game/VoxelGameGL.java) as a proof of concept.

I have found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118081/how-do-i-write-to-a-video-file-from-an-lwjgl-display) and a [forum post](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5128.0) but I was not able to make that work. I am a beginner on OpenGL and LWJGL and I am struggling on finding comprehensible documentation on that.

On the start of the render loop (`runUpdateAndRenderLoop`) the function `glBindFramebuffer` is called. To my understanding it binds FBO to the current context so that any rendering will be directed to it.

I have tried using `glGetTexImage` and `glReadPixels` to populate a ByteBuffer but it didnt work. I have also tried that after `glBlitFramebuffer` since I want to get the full rendered image to the ByteBuffer.

How can I render the current game scene to a ByteBuffer? Is there a better way of going about rendering game scenes to a video stream instead of an intermediate ByteBuffer?

```java
private void runAndUpdateRenderLoop() {
    // ...
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    byte[] pixels = new byte[width * height * 4];
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pixels.length).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Blindy is 100% correct and you should accept it as an answer.

However, if you want code for a *direct* working solution, then insert the following after

`glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);`

but *before*

`glfwSwapBuffers(window);`

The code:

```java
ByteBuffer bb = org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memAlloc(width * height * 4);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
// Test with stb_image to write as jpeg:
// org.lwjgl.stb.STBImageWrite.stbi_flip_vertically_on_write(true);
// org.lwjgl.stb.STBImageWrite.stbi_write_jpg("frame.jpg", width, height, 4, bb, 50);
org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memFree(bb);
```

This will result in the ByteBuffer `bb` to hold the pixel data of the current frame.

However, as also noted by @Blindy , this is a severe GPU stall, since you are forced to wait for the current frame's data to be fully rendered and force a GPU->CPU transfer into your ByteBuffer.
And Nvidia's drivers will also yell this to you when you enable debug message outputs:

`Pixel-path performance warning: Pixel transfer is synchronized with 3D rendering.`

Depending on your *actual* use-case, other approaches might be more useful, such as directly encoding a video from GPU memory (e.g. with NVENC).

Comment: I know @Blindy's answer is correct but the one you gave complemented it and helped me the most. The piece of code you provided made it much clearer to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of problems in your code, and that's without even seeing the core of the problem yet, since it's in the `// ...` part:

- You don't use `glfwSwapBuffers` when you're trying to render in a headless setup, that's only needed when you render to the context back buffer and want to swap it to screen.
- You don't want both `glGetTexImage` and `glReadPixels`, they both read data from graphics memory to system memory. In your case you're reading the texture data in `buffer` then overwriting it with the backbuffer data, which should be empty since you never wrote to it.
- You definitely do not want `glBlitFramebuffer`, that's for copying from video memory to video memory. You seriously need to stop and read the documentation, throwing random functions at your video driver is a sure way to make it crash.
- You need to enable OpenGL's debug layer validation, especially while trying all these random functions. And related, you need to check your frame buffer setup (`glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT`), I'm willing to bet money you didn't, but you don't show your code.
- You don't show your frame buffer bindings, so I can't tell if you're doing this for sure or not, but you need to bind the frame buffer as "read" (`GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`) before reading from it. I only see a "draw" frame buffer binding, and you're only randomly clearing it.
- And lastly, you should never stall the CPU on a read operation from video memory, especially when you have things you should be doing, like video encoding. Use pixel buffer objects in a round-robin fashion to double or triple buffer the transfer, so there's no stall.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. The full code is here: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/main/src/org/lwjgl/demo/game/VoxelGameGL.java

Comment: Right, thanks for making that clear. The code I posted for the `runAndUpdateRenderLoop` function on the SO question is an adaptation of the one present in the VoxelGame code I referenced. As I said, I am trying to extend VoxelGame to render to a ByteBuffer instead of a window. If you prefer I can provide the full code with my changes, but all I did is pretty much the code I presented in the SO question.